# Rmarkdown Chunk Name from Variable

Tags: r, r-markdown

How can I use a variable as the chunk name? I have a child document which gets called a number of times, and I need to advance the chunk labels in such a manner than I can also cross reference them.

Something like this:

**child.Rmd**

````
```{r }
if(!exists('existing')) existing <- 0
existing = existing + 1
myChunk <- sprintf("myChunk-%s",existing)
```

## Analysis Routine `r existing`

```{r myChunk,echo = FALSE}
#DO SOMETHING, LIKE PLOT
```
````

**master.Rmd**

````
# Analysis Routines

Analysis for this can be seen in figures \ref{myChunk-1}, \ref{myChunk-2} and \ref{myChunk-3}

```{r child = 'child.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'child.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'child.Rmd'}
```
````

**EDIT POTENTIAL SOLUTION**

Here is one potential workaround, inspired by SQL injection of all things...

**child.Rmd**

````
```{r }
if(!exists('existing')) existing <- 0
existing = existing + 1
myChunk <- sprintf("myChunk-%s",existing)
```

## Analysis Routine `r existing`

```{r myChunk,echo = FALSE,fig.cap=sprintf("The Caption}\\label{%s",myChunk)}
#DO SOMETHING, LIKE PLOT
```
````

Comment: Interesting question -- so you're asking about dynamic chunk names?  I'm not sure that it's possible... if you're more specific about what you're trying to do, there might be a valid workaround, like creating a list of plots and calling one at a time from the list...

Comment: I have modified the question to better reflect my issue.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I have posted a potential workaround, injecting the 'label' into the figure caption.

Comment: That's cool, maybe you should add it as an answer.  I don't have any good ideas here.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion to preknit the Rmd file into another Rmd file before knitting&rendering as follows

**master.Rmd:**

````
# Analysis Routines

Analysis for this can be seen in figures `r paste(paste0("\\ref{", CHUNK_NAME, 1:NUM_CHUNKS, "}"), collapse=", ")`

@@@
rmdTxt <- unlist(lapply(1:NUM_CHUNKS, function(n) {
    c(paste0("## Analysis Routine ", n),
        paste0("```{r ",CHUNK_NAME, n, ", child = 'child.Rmd'}"),
        "```")
}))
writeLines(rmdTxt)

@@@
````

**child.Rmd:**

````
```{r,echo = FALSE}
plot(rnorm(100))
```
````

To knit & render the Rmd:

```
devtools::install_github("chinsoon12/PreKnitPostHTMLRender")
library(PreKnitPostHTMLRender)   #requires version >= 0.1.1

NUM_CHUNKS <- 5
CHUNK_NAME <- "myChunk-"
preknit_knit_render_postrender("master.Rmd", "test__test.html")
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: for post HTML rendering i am using `` `%%% ` `` to identify codes to be parse...i think you just need the pre-knit portion...but your dynamic headers are in child document...let me take down my answer and think abt it some more

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting to this level of complexity, I suggest you look at the `brew` package.

That provides a templating engine where you can dynamically create the Rmd for knitting.

You get to reference R variables in the outer `brew` environment, and build you dynamic Rmd from there.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic chunk names are possible with knitr::knit_expand(). Arguments are referenced in the child document, including in the chunk headers, using {{arg_name}}.

So my parent doc contains:

````
```{r child_include, results = "asis"}
###
# Generate a section for each dataset
###
species <- c("a", "b")

out <- lapply(species, function(sp) knitr::knit_expand("child.Rmd"))

res = knitr::knit_child(text = unlist(out), quiet = TRUE)
cat(res, sep = "\n")
```
````

And my child doc, which has no YAML header, contains:

````
# EDA for species {{sp}}

```{r getname-{{sp}}}
paste("The species is", "{{sp}}")
```
````

See [here in the RMarkdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/knit-expand.html).